# Finding status changes in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with some state elections data that has a list of candidates 
who've run in different years. There's a program that some of them have participated in, and I'm interested in looking at why candidates move in and out of the program. What I want is a list of names of those who've participated in some years, but not in others. I'd like to eliminate from the list all the candidates who always or never participate.

The data looks a bit like this:

```
         names program year
1   Smith John       1 2008
2   Smith John       1 2010
3  Oliver Mary       0 2008
4  Oliver Mary       1 2010
5  Oliver Mary       1 2012
6 O'Neil Cathy       0 2010
7 O'Neil Cathy       1 2012
```

So in this case, I'd want to collect Mary Oliver and Cathy O'Neil in the list, but not John Smith. I thought of using group_by in dplyr, but I'm not sure where to go next. Any thoughts on how to set this operation up?

Comment: `df1 %>% group_by(names) %>% dplyr::filter(sum(program) != n())`? where `df1` is your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering out the ones where the sum of the values in the `program` column is less than the number of rows for each name in the `names` column. The following should do, I think:

#### Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(names = c("Smith John", "Smith John", "Oliver Mary", 
"Oliver Mary", "Oliver Mary", "ONeil Cathy", "ONeil Cathy"), 
    program = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), year = c(2008L, 
    2010L, 2008L, 2010L, 2012L, 2010L, 2012L)), .Names = c("names", 
"program", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

#### Code:

```
df1 %>% group_by(names) %>% dplyr::filter(sum(program) != n())
```

#### Output:

```
        names program  year
        <chr>   <int> <int>
1 Oliver Mary       0  2008
2 Oliver Mary       1  2010
3 Oliver Mary       1  2012
4 ONeil Cathy       0  2010
5 ONeil Cathy       1  2012
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Abdou!

I ended up doing something like this:

changedStatus <- df1 %>% group_by(names) %>% 
        dplyr::filter(sum(program) > 0 & sum(program) < n()) %>%
        distinct(names)